# How to Copy Visuals from Power BI Dashboar?

Tags: powerbi

Good Afternoon,
I'm trying to copy visuals from power bi dashboard and want to paste it on power point. But unfortunately, its not working. The more option (top right corner of the visuals) does not provide the option 'copy visual as image', but it gives option 'copy-visuals' which is not working.

Also the visuals heading (under formatting) does not  give option for 'copy icon'.
Someone would please advice me how can do copy and paste in this case?

Thank you

Comment: The copy visual as image may be disabled in the Power BI Tenancy settings for 'Export and sharing', you can request your admin to enable it. In Power BI Desktop the report designer can turn off the copy feature as well.

Comment: Its only me who use this desktop, there is no admin to ask. Therefore, its probably me lacking the technical knowledge.